# collapse one col and auto-adjust the other one

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm struggling with my user interface (bootstrap). I'm able to hide the `navbar` by clicking the left small button. That works pretty fine without any problems. Its done by `css` and some wrappers. But I'm not able to do the same functionality for the right side (green panel). I also tried to do it with the collapse class. If I do it that way, the main content (red window) does not auto scale for the full available space to the right. So how is it possible to hide the green panel and scale the red content on the full width? This can be done by `CSS` or `JavaScript`. Any help would be appreciated.

**Fiddle:**  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27545/

**CSS:**

```
/* Sidebar Navigation Style */
.nav-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 175px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

/*          Wrapper           */
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 175px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

/*       Sidebar Wrapper      */
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -205px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/*       Main SVG Content     */
#visualization {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100vh; /* aspect ratio */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar sidebar">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a>NavBar</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- End Sidebar Wrapper -->
    <div class="row" id="row-main-content">
        <div class="col-xs-9" style="background-color: red">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-indent-right" id="btnHide"></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt pull-right" id="btnHide2"></button>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="visualization">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- End Page Content Wrapper -->
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-right: 0px">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body" style="height: 100vh; background-color: green">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- End Panel Wrapper -->
    </div> <!-- End Row -->
</div> <!-- End Wrapper -->
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
/* Functionality for Toggle Sidebar Button */
$("#btnHide").click(function () {
    $(this).tooltip("hide");
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem now with the help of a little bit of `jQuery`

**updated Fiddle:**  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27617/

`jQuery Part` for my problem:

```
$("#btnHide2").click(function () {
    $(this).tooltip("hide");

    if ($('#panel-wrapper').hasClass('collapse')) {
        $('#page-content-wrapper').removeClass('col-xs-12').addClass('col-xs-9');
        $('#panel-wrapper').removeClass('collapse')
    }
    else {
        $('#page-content-wrapper').removeClass('col-xs-9').addClass('col-xs-12');
        $('#panel-wrapper').addClass('collapse')
    }
});
```

Comment: Please publish the link to your solution.